# jqplot line chart legend oversize

Tags: cakephp, jqplot

I have a jqplot for a line graph but my legend is becoming too huge. I want to implement a scrollable functionality for the legend. I tried to do the following :

```
table.jqplot-table-legend {
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

in the css file and in my ctp file, i tried

```
legend: { 
    show: true, 
    location: 'ne',
    rendererOptions: {numberColumns: 2}
}
```

as was mentioned in previous posts but none seem to work for me. 
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I apply your css before or after the chart has rendered, it works fine with one change. I had to increase it's z-index so the scroll bar is on top and clickable.  Here's an example of applying it after the chart has rendered:

```
plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', data, opts);

var legendTable = $($('.jqplot-table-legend')[0]);    
legendTable.css('display','block');
legendTable.css('z-index',100);
legendTable.css('height','100px');
legendTable.css('overflow-y','scroll');
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/Czu38/).